# Drupal 7 theme "front" differs from other pages

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I need a custom template for the 'frontpage' and a custom template for all the other pages.

What are the best practices to accomplish this?

Do I need to make 2 themes or can I use the same theme?

Answer (score 3):

Create 2 template files:

1. `page--front.tpl.php` for the front page.
2. `page.tpl.php` for other pages.

For further reading, check out [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656).

Don't forget to clear the site cache after the creation of each new template file.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to direct you towards "The Drupal Way" (do it with flexible UI-based modules) if you are not already familiar with.

I would approach this problem using [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and possibly [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) if you need to display listed information on the page (such as a news-feed or similar).

This gives a whole different approach to setting up your site's content displays and it is the general direction of the Drupal ecosystem.

Comment: Really unclear why you felt the need to change my grammar. As well as me intentionally using "the Drupal way" as "The Drupal Way" since it is a concept that is worth reading up on. Worth distinguishing as the starting sentence makes less sense now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Drupal theming, try using the Devel and the Themer Developer module (http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer)